# Modify Graylog2 Web interface

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, graylog2

I am using [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) 2.2.1 in Ubuntu 14.04. I want to modify the Graylog web interface a bit, such as adding some link, some panel, images..., I tried to find the directory contain graylog web files. In `/etc/graylog-server/` I can found only the server.conf, not any web files.
I tried to use search in Ubuntu with keyword "graylog" but there is no folder which I can see the web files inside it.
So, where is the Graylog's web UI files location?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Graylog API for customizing everything such as dashboard widgets.